# C++: Passing reference of constructing object to constructed member objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

Okay, consider the following classes:

```
class Object
{
public:
    // Constructor
    Object() : 
        [Initialization List]
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
};

class Container
{
public:
    Object A;
    Object B;

    ....

    Container() :
        [Initialization List]
    {
    }
};
```

I'd like to provide [access to Container and it's members] to the Objects.

My first thought was to somehow pass a reference to the current Container object to the constructors of the Objects.  But I can't figure out how to do this.

I've messed around with "this", but I'm not getting anything that works.  I tried something like this:

```
class Object
{
public:
    Container& c

    // Constructor
    Object(Container& c_) : 
        c(c_)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
};

class Container
{
public:
    Object A;
    Object B;

    ....

    Container() :
        A(Object(this))
        B(Object(this))
    {
    }
};
```

My eventual goal is to be able to access Object B from inside a member method of Object A.

Does anyone have any insight on how to get closer to what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *not* UB *or* bad, necessarily, to use `this` in an initializer list, although care is needed, and your code is perfectly valid with minor modification.

```
class Container;
class Object
{
public:
    Container& c

    // Constructor
    Object(Container& c_) : 
        c(c_)
    {
    }
};

class Container
{
public:
    Object A;
    Object B;

    Container() :
        A(Object(*this))
        B(Object(*this))
    {
    }
};
```

`this` is a pointer, you wanted a reference, and a simple de-reference will do the trick. This is perfectly legal and defined code. What's not allowed is to access any member data or functions through the pointer, because those member data or functions simply may not exist yet until the init list is finished. But it definitely *is* allowed to take a pointer or reference to an object during it's initializer list and pass it around.

Comment: I can edit the "can't" to be a "shouldn't", but I've used compilers that will reject your code or misbehave on it, so your solution definitely is not portable. Also note the *IIRC* in my comment about the UB - as you pointed out in chat, the standard allows it. That doesn't make is portable, nor necessarily a good idea.

Comment: @RonaldLandheer-Cieslak: [Your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905498/c-passing-reference-of-constructing-object-to-constructed-member-objects/5905534#comment-6797641) says "IIRC", but your answer does not.  With which compilers does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

How about just using pointers? **Edit**: fixed code to avoid `this` in initializer list.

```
class Container;

class Object
{
public:
    Container *c;

    // Constructor
    Object(Container *c_) : 
        c(c_)
    {
    }
};

class Container
{
public:
    Object *A, *B;

    Container()
    {
        A = new Object(this);
        B = new Object(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thats actually what I have right now, but I get compile error noting that it is looking for Object::Object(Object).  My constructor is, of course, Object::Object(Container *)

Comment: @jedwards in the code you provided the constructor is `Object::Object(Container&)`, not `Object::Object(Container*)`. That said, it is a *bad* idea to pass `this` in an initializer list - IIRC, it's UB

Comment: @jedwards, I forgot the forward declaration `class Container`, that should fix the error. @Ronald, I wasn't aware that it was UB. I suppose A and B should be pointers, then, which are set in the constructor itself.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't pass `this` in initializers for members of the class whose instance you're constructing, but you can pass it later, so there's two easy ways around your problem

- use a setter on the object (`A.setContainer(*this)`) in the constructor's body
- make A and B pointers, initialize them to `NULL` and do a `A = new Object(this)` in the constructor's body

Comment: Thank you for the concise and clear explanation of what I was doing wrong -- all is well in container/object-ville now!

Comment: @Fred not portably, you can't

Comment: [Is it safe to bind a reference to a not yet constructed object in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815689/is-it-safe-to-bind-a-reference-to-a-not-yet-constructed-object-in-c/4815754#4815754) "In a nutshell: don't access any members, methods, or pass it to anything that does. You can take its address and bind references to it."

Comment: @Ronald: You can, you just shouldn't access any members. It's a normal pointer after all, i.e. an address.

Comment: @Xeo: You can de-reference it too, to get a reference. You just can't access anything.