# Can you static_cast "this" to a derived class in a base class constructor then use the result later?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, static-cast

We ran into this scenario in our codebase at my work, and we had a big debate over whether this is valid C++ or not. Here is the simplest code example I could come up with:

```
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    A() { subclass = static_cast<T*>(this); }
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
protected:
    T* subclass;
};

class C : public A<C> {
public:
    C(int i) : i(i) { }
    virtual void Foo() { subclass->Bar(); }
    void Bar() { std::cout << "i is " << i << std::endl; }
private:
    int i;
};

int main() {
    C c(5);
    c.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This code works 100% of the time in practice (as long as the template parameter type matches the subclass type), but if we run it through a runtime analyzer, it tells us that the `static_cast` is invalid because we're casting `this` to a `C*` but the `C` constructor hasn't run yet. Sure enough, if we change the `static_cast` to a `dynamic_cast`, it returns `nullptr` and this program will fail and crash when accessing `i` in `Bar()`.

My intuition is that it should always be possible to replace `static_cast` with `dynamic_cast` without breaking your code, suggesting that the original code in fact is depending on compiler-specific undefined behavior. However, [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) it says:

> If the object expression refers or points to is actually a base class subobject of an object of type D, the result refers to the enclosing object of type D.

The question being, is it a base class subobject of an object of type `D` before the object of type `D` has finished being constructed? Or is this undefined behavior? My level of C++ rules lawyering is not strong enough to work this out.

Comment: You probably want to add the `language-lawyer` tag.  I think this is legit provided you don't dereference the `subclass` pointer too soon.  There may be more caveats if multiple inheritance is involved.

Comment: Actually, `dynamic_cast` in this situation is guaranteed to not work.

Comment: @user17732522 The analyzer says: "runtime error: downcast of address 0x61a0000000c8 which does not point to an object of type 'C'". Also the cast is not to A<C> but rather to C (which is T).

Comment: Here's one possible duplicate/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815689/is-it-safe-to-bind-a-reference-to-a-not-yet-constructed-object-in-c -- if it's good enough for a reference it should be good enough for a pointer. I am not going to close this question as a duplicate, myself. If another gold-badger think it is, they can do that themselves...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That seems different. There a member of the derived class is referenced. I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to cast the base pointer under the same conditions, but honestly the relevant parts of the standard are quite confusingly written in my opinion.

Comment: The member class is also not constructed at all. If you can have a pointer or a reference to a subclass's member, before the subclass is constructed, then why can't you have a pointer or a reference to the subclass itself, @user17732522?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik As I said these parts of the standard are very confusing to me as well. In particular it is not clear whether an object is considered under construction when its constructor starts execution or only when all of its base classes have been constructed. [\[class.cdtor\]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#1.sentence-1) seems to specifically require only the former to refer to members and [class.cdtor]/3 gives restrictions on derived-to-base casts, but there is nothing specifically about base-to-derived casts in there. But I would be surprised if this was not intended to be ok.

Comment: Why do you keep a member `subclass` as you can have an inline function `T &GetT()` that woould do the cast? Having said that I don't there is any problem with that code.

Comment: @user17732522 _it is not clear whether an object is considered under construction when its constructor starts execution or only when all of its base classes have been constructed_ https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1517.html?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer But the suggested _period of construction_ can't be intended to also apply to the _under construction_ in [\[basic.life\]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-6.sentence-2) and the _construction [...] shall have started_ in [\[class.cdtor\]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#3), can it?  It would make the `X(this)` case in the example given there undefined, wouldn't it? Also, does `static_cast<Derived*>(base_ptr)` require the derived object to be in its lifetime? (I guess not, since there is no specific requirement stated in [expr.static.cast]?)

Comment: @Phil1970 This was simplified from the original code. Original code was doing like a registry/vector per subtype so it was more complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion this is well-defined according to the current wording of the standard: the `C` object exists at the time of the `static_cast`, although it is under construction and its lifetime has not yet begun. This would seem to make the `static_cast` well-defined according to [expr.static.cast]/11, which reads in part:

> ... If the prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a base class subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

It doesn't say that the `D` object's lifetime must have begun.

We might also want to look at the explicit rule about when it becomes legal to perform an implicit conversion from derived to base, [[class.cdtor]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#3):

> To explicitly or implicitly convert a pointer (a glvalue) referring to an object of class `X` to a pointer (reference) to a direct or indirect base class `B` of `X`, the construction of `X` and the construction of all of its direct or indirect bases that directly or indirectly derive from `B` shall have started and the destruction of these classes shall not have completed, otherwise the conversion results in undefined behavior. To form a pointer to (or access the value of) a direct non-static member of an object `obj`, the construction of `obj` shall have started and its destruction shall not have completed, otherwise the computation of the pointer value (or accessing the member value) results in undefined behavior.

According to this rule, as soon as the compiler starts constructing the base class `A<C>`, it is well-defined to implicitly convert from `C*` to `A<C>*`. Before that point, it results in UB. The reason for this, basically, has to do with virtual base classes: if the path by which `A<C>` is inherited by `C` contains any virtual inheritance, the conversion may rely on data that are set up by one of the constructors in the chain. For a conversion from base to derived, if there is indeed any virtual inheritance on the chain, `static_cast` will not compile, so we don't really need to ask ourselves the question, *but are those data sufficient for going the other way?*

I really can't see anything in the text of the standard, nor any rationale, for the `static_cast` in your example not being well-defined, nor in any other case of `static_cast`ing from base to derived when the reverse implicit conversion (or `static_cast`) would be allowed (excepting the case of virtual inheritance, which as I said before, leads to a compile error anyway).

(Would it be well-defined to do it even earlier? In most cases this won't be possible; how could you possibly attempt to `static_cast` from `B*` to `D*` before the conversion from `D*` to `B*` is allowed, without having obtained the `B*` pointer precisely by doing the latter? If the answer is that you got from `D*` to `B*` through an intermediate base class `C1` whose constructor has started, but there is another intermediate base class `C2` sharing the same `B` base class subobject and its construction hasn't started yet, then `B` is a virtual base class, and again, this means the compiler will stop you from then trying to `static_cast` from `B*` back down to `D*`. So I think there are no issues left to resolve here.)