Access address of derived class data member in mixin constructor
In my code I have a system as outlined by the following code:
// Base class to make derived objects polymorphic
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

void registerData(int*) {}

template <typename Derived>
struct RegisterMixin {
    static int (Derived::*dataPtr); // Defined for each derived class

    RegisterMixin() {
        auto* derived = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
        registerData(&(derived->*dataPtr));
    }
};

struct MyDerived: Base, RegisterMixin<MyDerived> {
    int myData; // Will be set by the enclosing system
};

template <>
int MyDerived::*RegisterMixin<MyDerived>::dataPtr = &MyDerived::myData;

int main() {
    MyDerived derived;
}

The intent is that whenever an object derived from RegisterMixin is constructed, its data member will be registered in a global map so it can be controlled by an enclosing system.
If I run the program with UB sanitizer it complains about the static_cast<Derived*> in the RegisterMixin constructor that the object is not of type Derived. I assume the error is justified because the RegisterMixin constructor runs before the Derived constructor.
However I don't actually do anything with the derived object, I only access its address. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying here without invoking UB?
https://godbolt.org/z/YK8dKc47W

Under common sense this is a false positive. I'd silence it with a pragma and move on.

@HolyBlackCat I'd think so too, but this is the first statement under Issue supression in the documentation: "UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer is not expected to produce false positives." -- And then Chandler Carruth once said in a talk that LLVM will potentially optimize on anything flagged by UBSan, so I'm somewhat hesitant to ignore it.

I don't think a sane compiler would optimize this. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180292/2752075

On E1.*E2: "If the result of E1 is an object whose type is not similar to the type of E1, or whose most derived object does not contain the member to which E2 refers, the behavior is undefined." expr.mptr.oper

@HolyBlackCat Thanks, this is what I wanted to see :-) I guess my question could be closed as duplicate.

@molbdnilo Arguably though this is of derived type MyDerived, even though the MyDerived object is not constructed yet. That's at least the argument in the answer linked by HolyBlackCat.

@chrysante It's fine to cast this to the derived type and use it later, once the derived object has been constructed. It is not fine to dereference the pointer-to-member in the constructor since "the most derived object" is not a MyDerived at that point.

@molbdnilo I'm not sure where you get that the most derived object is not a MyDerived. After all, the construction of MyDerived has already begun at that point, albeit not completed.

@chrysante sure, when I make software, I generally like to say "it works" too. Still, you can either look at your code, decide its okay, and get rid of the warning the easy way -- or you can spend a lot of time making complicated, difficult to read and generally unmaintainable workarounds.

@ChristianStieber sorry, I don't really get what you are trying to say? Should I leave it as is or not?

" The bottom line is this: even if the caller is constructing an object of a derived class, during the constructor of the base class, your object is not yet of that derived class. You have been warned." from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180292/12173376, which cites https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#using-this-in-ctors. If we were to take this literally, I would interpret the static_cast in the ctor as UB. Not sure about the real world consequences though.

This is the best that I can come up with, but that rules out default construction for derived classes: https://godbolt.org/z/sforG5fMc

Leaving the binding to an external function might be helpful:void registerClass(void*, std::function<int*(void*)>); then: registerClass(this,[](void* x){return &(static_cast<derived*>(static_cast<Mixin*>(x))->*data_ptr);});. The registerClass function is intentionally using std:: function to avoid template inlining; if it is defined in a different module, then visibility may decrease.
